# Compare SHA2_512 C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to compare password when user logins from ASP.NET Site to One I generated for him in SQL Server.

So, I generate password field in SQL server like this:

```
insert into users 
select 'username',  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'password'))
```

And code in C#:

```
string text = Password;
            SHA512 alg = SHA512.Create();
            byte[] result = alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            string hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

And those two hashes are very different.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: SHA 512 is too fast for passwords.  Use salted bcrypt.

Comment: Hash results are not valid UTF8.  Use Base64.

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR is a 16-bit encoding — most likely little-endian UTF-16. `HASHBYTES` is therefore probably seeing a different input to `ComputeHash`.

Try `Encoding.Unicode`.

Also, don't use `Encoding` to convert `result` to a string. It contains raw bytes, not encodings of characters. If you want a string, convert the bytes to [hex digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) or [Base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).